# Search Box not working in Firefox Developer Edition's Inspector

Tags: firefox, inspector

I've just download the latest version of FireFox Developer Edition and I'm playing around with the Inspector.

The SEARCH BOX is not working.

It does NOT find anything...

Am I missing something or is it a bug of this version ?